# Can't use react hook inside a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use the react hook `useEffect` inside a function called EditForm.

It keeps telling me:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

But I am using it inside the function called EditForm.

So I am not sure why it thinks it's not in a function.

Is there a way to make it work?

Here is my code:

```
const EditForm = ({
idVal, titleVal, sectionVal, factoryId, departmentId, countryId, dictionName, showMeVal }) => (

const [pcData, setPcData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const result = await axios(
            'api/manufacturingData',
        );
        setPcData(result.data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)));
    };
    fetchData();
}, []);
    <div className="app">

        <Formik
            initialValues={{
                id: idVal,
                title: titleVal
        ....etc />
```

Comment: I think your component itself is fine - it's probably where you are using the component. Can you show that part?

Comment: This might be a mistake in transcribing your code, but do you have an open parenthesis rather than an open brace?

Comment: thanks, where? I can't seem to find anything

Comment: your pasted function code is declared as `({ stuff }) => ()`, instead `({ stuff }) => { // doStuff; return <div>content</div> }`. the first one is valid only if the content is an expression that resolves in some jsx like `({ stuff }) => (<div>content</div>)` or `({ stuff }) => (stuff && <div>content</div>)`

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your code like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const EditForm = ({
  idVal,
  titleVal,
  sectionVal,
  factoryId,
  departmentId,
  countryId,
  dictionName,
  showMeVal,
}) => {
  
  const [pcData, setPcData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios("api/manufacturingData");
      setPcData(result.data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)));
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return <div>Your content</div>;
};

export default EditForm;
```